# How to check INSERT action on compound columns using trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the next tables: faculty, faculty_subjects and subjects. Every faculty has a list of subjects

[image: db schema]

And I want to use check in faculty_subjects table such as - every faculty should not have the same subject multiple times. So every record in `faculty_subjects` table has a unique pair `Faculty_idFaculty` - `Subject_idSubject`.

I was trying to add trigger that is listed below:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Faculty_Subjects_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `Faculty_Subjects` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- throw exception when condition not satisfied
    IF ( (NEW.`Subject_idSubject`= `Subject_idSubject`) AND (NEW.`Faculty_idFaculty`= `Faculty_idFaculty`)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This faculty already add this subject as preliminary', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
    END IF;
END;
```

But I get errors such `1109` or `1054`. How this functionality can be achieved ?

I'm using MySQL database.

Comment: You can ged rid of the `id` in `Facility_Subjects` and you will have the unique pairs you want.

Comment: @CamiloR yes, I think of it. but in the future as new columns appearing and maybe some business logic will changed isn't it will be harder to maintain a table without such unique id field, that doesn't depend on other tables ?